# Cant set innerHTML of Dropdown Menu equal to the variable of an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, http

I'm working on a small website which i want to be able to change their dropdown menus depending on the content that i insert into a google docs file.

The code to read such content is already working fine, but now i can't set the innerHTML of my dropdown menu equal to the content of the array... Every time I try to open the dropdown it simply shows the elements with the title "undefined".

If i print the array however, it shows the correct content.

This is written via script.google for a small company I'm doing a internship for, it is written using mainly javascript, googlescript and html.

```
//IN CODE.gs File
function SheetNames(i) {
       var app = SpreadsheetApp;
       var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Options");  
       var name = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
       return name;
    }

//IN HTML File
var x = new Array();
function catcher(name){      
        x[i] = name;
        return x;
}

window.onload = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(catcher).SheetNames(i+2);
          var node = document.createElement("A"); 
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(x[i]);
          node.appendChild(textnode);              
          node.id = i;
          node.value = x[i];
          document.getElementById("userdrp").appendChild(node);  
          document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = x[i];
        }
}
```

Expected is that the single created elements of the dropdown menu will show me the correct corresponding content in the google file.

Comment: This doesn't apply to your, question, but you don't have to do ``var x = new Array();`` in order to define a new array. You can just define an empty array like this: ``var x = [];``

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you :D thats fairly convenient

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that the "i" in your catcher function is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I am now work with gs and google sheets api, but maybe here 

    `//IN HTML File
    var x = new Array();
    function catcher(name){
        x[i] = name;
        return x;
    }` 
variable i is not define?

Comment: i is defined, i failed to copy it into it ^^

Comment: You also can simplify your code. 
`var node = document.createElement("A");
            node.innerText = x[i];
            //var textnode = document.createTextNode(x[i]);
            //node.appendChild(textnode);
            node.id = i;
            //node.value = x[i];
            document.getElementById("userdrp").appendChild(node);`